Looking for WRITTABLE RESQUE linux distro for USB drive under 8GB installed
Looking for WRITTABLE resque/recovery type LINUX distro for USB flash drive under 8GB installed.
Current primary usage scenario: write and troubleshoot initramfs script for non-standard boot process (details doesn't really matter here).
By "resque type" I mean without heavy stuff like office/video/multimedia, not necessary loaded with all kinds of recovery tools.
Should support/have:

minor soft installation and fstab, other /etc files modification (i.e. ROOTFS need to be WRITTABLE, or /etc at least)
mount of LUKS + BTRFS partitions & subvolumes
able to run Bash scripts
have (or be able to install) plain text editor (will be used for shell scripts editing)
Terminal
Chroot (or be able to install)

I tried Systemresque 10.02, which has touchpad DISABLED (there's a ticket on gitlab for 3 years about this).
One cannot even install any of recent versions 11.x with their own USBWriter, and has other issues noticable almost immediately.
Otherwise Systemresque would fit the target.
Haven't given up on Systemresque completely yet though.
Most of the time I spend in dual panel file manager or in terminal, therefore GUI isn't important.
Interface similar to Cinnamon or Windows 7 would be best if there's a choice, but again not important.
This is a laptop with 1 disk, therefore installing full size distro to another disk is not an option.
Thank you.

Install a regular distribution onto the USB stick. Any Linux system can boot from a USB disk with only minor configuration; Alpine or Arch may be a good start. (A minimal Alpine installation will be below 1 GB, with the kernel and firmware blobs being largest.)

partition;
mkfs and mount;
pacstrap Arch, or untar the Alpine bootstrap;
don't forget to install a Linux kernel – and a bootloader;
chroot and configure, grub-install, mkinitcpio, and so on.

The entire / rootfs will be writable and persistent.

Thank you! Could you please give more details on step 3? Don't know yet whats pacstrap and bootstrap?

Looks like I'll need to choose/install DE myself on Alpine. Anybody knows how much space XFCE will take on Alpine? Or any other DE suggestion for small space usage? (hopefully with similar location of window buttons as Win7 or Cinnamon). RAM usage doesn't matter.

Tried Alpine + XFCE (XFCE installed with setup-desktop) several times on 2 different flash drives - it hangs w/o any error message and totally black screen. Only Alpine standard w/o XFCE boots fine. Looks like at least Alpine+XFCE not really tested for USB boot. Not sure how to troubleshoot. My laptop is old and should be very well tested/supported by now.
